# How can I merge the values from two pandas dataframe which as same row and column indexes/value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

In the following pandas dataframe:

```
d1 = pd.read_csv('to_count.mcve.txt', sep='\t')
d1 = d1.set_index(['pos'], append=True)

       M1           M2       F1   F2
  pos                        
0 23   A,B,A,C,D    A,C,B    A    D
1 24   A,B,B,C,B    A,B,A    B    B
2 28   C,B,C,D,E    B,C      E    C
```

I used the below code to do some counting:

```
hapX_count = pd.DataFrame()
hapY_count = pd.DataFrame()
for index, lines in d1.iterrows():
    hap_x = lines['F1']
    hap_y = lines['F2']
    x_count = lines.apply(lambda x: x.count(hap_x)/2 if len(x) > 5 else x.count(hap_x))
    y_count = lines.apply(lambda x: x.count(hap_y)/2 if len(x) > 5 else x.count(hap_y))

    hapX_count = hapX_count.append(x_count)
    hapY_count = hapY_count.append(y_count)
```

Output for hapX_count:

```
print(hapX_count)

         F1   F2   M1   M2
(0, 23)  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
(1, 24)  1.0  1.0  1.5  1.0
(2, 28)  1.0  0.0  0.5  0.0
```

Output for hapY_count:

```
print(hapY_count)

         F1   F2   M1   M2
(0, 23)  0.0  1.0  0.5  0.0
(1, 24)  1.0  1.0  1.5  1.0
(2, 28)  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

How may I combine the values (which have same `column` and `row` indexes) inside these dataframe with a comma?

**Expected output like:**

```
         F1       F2       M1       M2
(0, 23)  1.0,0.0  0.0,1.0  1.0,0.5  1.0,0.0
same for other lines...
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You could go ahead and do the concatenation inside your for loop. However, if you are set on doing the concatenation after the fact and want them separated by commas, then I assume you are okay with the data becoming strings instead of floats. If that is the case, and you know that the columns and indexes are identical and in the same order, you can do:

```
df = hapX_count.astype(str) + ',' + hapY_count.astype(str)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not working as expected. it does merge the values in each cell, but the different cell values are merged with different cell values. I also tried concatenating within the for loop but no luck.